# Why is my jQuery script not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked at dozens of Stack Overflow questions and Googled a thousand different solutions and I just can't seem to figure out the problem. I'm a total noob to web development and I just want [this simple page](https://sheiladaniels.000webhostapp.com/) to work. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong? It's probably a really dumb mistake with an easy solution.I do apologize in advance. Thanks!

#### My HTML head:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sheila Mary Daniels</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Local scripts and sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type = "text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7dd8dcb030.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Sofia" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

#### My CSS:

(which works just fine)

```
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-image: url("https://flowerillust.com/img/flower/flower-back0950.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

#image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: Purple;
  font-family: Dancing Script;
  /* font-family: Sofia */
}

.scripture {
  font-family: Dancing Script;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

#### My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").hide().fadeIn(5000);
  $("#image").hide().fadeIn(5000);
});
```

I know there's nothing wrong with my code because [my CodePen](https://codepen.io/RyanED/full/GEOvVQ/) works just fine. Both my CSS and my JS are external files. As you can see the CSS works perfectly. No idea what I'm doing wrong with the JS.

#### EDIT:

I've reordered my `<link>` and `<script>` tags as the comments suggested and still nothing.

Comment: what error message do you receive in the console?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser and check the error console.  Get used to doing that.

Comment: @ZombieChowder Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at script.js:1

Comment: This is because jquery is loaded after bootstrap. When bootstrap loads it look for jquery. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want to include jQuery first, then bootstrap (or other downloaded scripts that depends of jQuery), then your custom script

so it would be like this

```
<!-- jQuery -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQueryUI -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7dd8dcb030.js"></script>
<!-- custom script -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Is your answer different from other two answer.

Comment: Just by a bit, the difference is that there is a small explanation on how to do it and I specified that the custom code should be included after the others

Comment: @Ved Yes it is. I tried the other two answers and they didn't work. I was not putting my custom script right at the end.I did give them upvotes because they were right.

Answer (score 2):

change the order of your js files

use JQuery first

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type = "text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add Jquery before bootstap.js file. This may be the potential reason.Just try after reordering it.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
     src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```